# "eth0 does not seem to be present" on RedHat despite new MAC address

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, redhat, virtual-machines

I created a RedHat VM (6.5) on an Ubuntu (14.04) server.  I changed the IP address to something unique in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.  I changed the MAC address for eth0 /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.  I've never been able to give this new RedHat VM an IP address.  eth0 never comes up.  I get an error about eth0 does not seem to be present.  What should I do to give this VM an IP address?

Comment: Does dmesg say anything about your network card? Does "ifconfig -a" show anything?

Comment: ifconfig -a looks good.  dmesg has very few and only insignificant occurrences of the word "network."  dmesg has no references to "card."

Comment: I meant something more like "dmesg | grep eth"

Comment: Can you please provide the contents of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0? Can you try /sbin/service network restart and also try ifup eth0 and ifdown eth0?

Comment: DEVICE=eth0 BOOTPROTO=static ONBOOT=yes IPADDR=x.x.x.x NETMASK=255.255.255.0 GATEWAY=x.x.x.1 MACADDR=34:ab:cd:ef:99:aa   I tried those network restart and ifdown and ifup commands.  No luck.

Comment: I don't have RedHat so I'm not sure if ifup is a bash script. But if it is, you can run "bash -x ifup eth0" to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, it must be

```
BOOTPROTO=none
```

instead of

```
BOOTPROTO=static
```

as, in RHEL 6, this option is not supported anymore.